# Unity. Динамически скрыть Images под другим Image

Tags: unity3d, изображения, ui, mask, unity-canvas

Canvas. Например у меня есть список картинок (компонент Image), которые скролятся(двигаются сверху вниз). И на определенную область списка, накладывается другая png картинка(так же компонент Image), у которой есть прозрачные области.

Как можно под наложенной картинкой(с учетом прозрачных областей), скрывать двигающиеся картинки?

Про маски знаю, но эту задачу они не решают по 2 причинам:

1) "Канвасная" маска отображается только внутри(only visible inside mask).

2) "Канвасная" маска работает только с дочерним объектом(Накладываемых картинок может быть множество).

Sprite Rendere не подходит, так как это должно быть все в канвасе.

Может у кого есть какие-то идеи?
Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: RectMask2D пробовали?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker да, этот компонент также работает внутрь(only visible inside mask)

Answer (score 0):

- Да, внутри, так маскирование и работает в принцепе, хоть в `Unity3d`, хоть в `Photoshop`.
  Очень редко где есть такой инструмент, как обратная маска.

  [image: Mask]
- Да, на дочерние и почему же это обстоятельство непреодолимой силы? Никакой проблемы в этом нет. Маску можно генирировать с помощью сгенерированной `Texture2D`, хотя придётся чуть посидеть.

Comment: В сущности, это всё уточнения, на вопрос это сообщение не отвечает =/

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik уточнения? оправержения! картинка...

Comment: Но вопрос же был "Как можно под наложенной картинкой(с учетом прозрачных областей), скрывать двигающиеся картинки?". P.S. минус не мой)

Comment: Не всегда люди задающие вопрос реализуют верное решение, порой в корне не верное или поная дичь, как в данном случае, когда автор не разобравшись в инструменте посчитал нормальный функционал дифектным и хочет искать что-то там ещё, чего нет. Если не твой, значит ByArper =D

Comment: @Yaroslav я не считаю функционал дефектным, возможно я не полностью изучил данный функционал, по этому прошу помощи на портале.
P.S. минус я не ставил.